# how to make a moving object to centre html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

hey there I have a game here https://green-snake.glitch.me and what I want to do is when the object moves by arrow keys not to hide behind canvas borders

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Change the following in your header:

```css
body,html { /* Remove margins */
 margin: 0px;
 position: relative;
 width:  100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;         
}
canvas { /* Center the canvas */
 margin:auto;
 border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

to this:

```css
body,html { /* Remove margins */
 margin: 0px;
 position: relative;
 width:  100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;         
}
canvas { /* Center the canvas */
 margin:auto;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 display:block;
}
```

Basically add `display:block;` to your `canvas` element.